# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have tried to make a spring boot project, but when I put a  dependency inside pom file, there is an error.  I have tried reach  http://repo.spring.io url and it can be reachable.  I tried to change the proxy settings and the problem was not solved.  Even settings.xml I removed and checked.
I have mentioned in below my maven and JDK version.

Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin**apache-maven-3.6.3**\bin..
Java version: 15.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java**jdk-15.0.1**

Below is my **pom** file dependencies.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dm.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>springboot-demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Springboot  Demo App</name>

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>`
```

Below is my **settings.xml**

```
 <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<proxies>

<proxy>
  <id>example-proxy</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>proxy.example.com</host>
  <port>8080</port>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>somepassword</password>
  <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying your actual proxy host and port in the `~/.m2/settings.xml` and remove the username and password if you can establish the connection without specifying username and password.

```xml
<host>Your Proxy Host Here</host>
<port>Your Proxy Port Here</port>
```

If both username and password is required to establish the connection, use your actual credentials like this:

```xml
<host>Your Proxy Host Here</host>
<port>Your Proxy Port Here</port>
<username>Your Username Here</username>
<password>Your Password Here</password>
```

Comment: user name and password of my internet connection? and host meant localhost:port ?

Comment: No, host name means just the host name, if you want to specify the port you can specify it in <port>